# Error:does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method

Tags: c#, windows-forms

queria saber que provoca este tipo de error? antes me salia

> Member '' cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Pero instancie la clase y funciono pero me dio ese nuevo error

```
using Parrot.Kitchen.App.Controller;
using Parrot.Kitchen.Business.Entities.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Parrot.Kitchen.App.Forms
{
    public partial class NewConfiguration : Form
    {
        private BizKitchenNEWConfiguration bizKitchenNEWConfiguration;
        private KitchenSetupController kitchenSetupController;
        private MessageForm messageForm;
        private ConfirmForm confirmForm;
        private string TextMessage;
        public bool IsReleased;

        private int MaxCommand;
        private int MaxMinute;

        private int MinCommand;
        private int MinMinute;

        private int Command;
        private int Minute;


        public NewConfiguration()
        {
            this.BizKitchenNEWConfiguration = bizKitchenNEWConfiguration;
            this.messageForm = new MessageForm();
            this.TextMessage = String.Empty;
            this.confirmForm = new ConfirmForm();
            this.IsReleased = false;


            this.MaxCommand = 99;
            this.MaxMinute = 60;

            this.MinMinute = 0;
            this.MinCommand = 0;

            this.Command = 0;
            this.Minute = 0;

            var NEWkitchen = new BizKitchenNEWConfiguration();

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public BizKitchenNEWConfiguration GetNEWKitchenSetup()
        {
            return this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration;

        }

        }
        private void SaveConfiguration()


        {
            try
            {

               this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands = Int32.Parse(this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text);
                this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupMinutes = Int32.Parse(this.TxtMinuteGrouping.Text);
                this.NEWkitchen.IsReleased = this.TxtGroupingRelease.Text;

              //  this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands = Int32.Parse(this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text);
                this.TextMessage = "La configuración fue guardada con éxito.";
                this.ShowMessageForm();
                this.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                this.TextMessage = "Hubo un error, porfavor intente de nuevo.";
                this.ShowMessageForm();
            }
        }

        private void NewConfiguration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // this.Owner.Enabled = false;

           this.Minute = this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupMinutes;
           this.Command = this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands;
            this.TxtMinuteGrouping.Text = (this.Minute).ToString();
            this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text = (this.Command).ToString();
            this.TxtGroupingRelease.Text = this.NEWkitchen.IsReleaseGroupedComms;
           //if (this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsConfirmsRelease.Equals("SI")) this.CkbReleaseCommand.Checked = true;
          //  else this.CkbReleaseCommand.Checked = false;
           /* this.Location = new Point(
                ((this.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
                ((this.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
            );*/
        }
```

El punto es que quiero guardar en la bd los datos

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Parrot.Kitchen.Business
{
    public class BizKitchenNewConfiguration
    {
        public int GroupMinutes { get; set; }
        public int GroupCommands { get; set; }
       public static string IsReleaseGroupedComms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trata de publicar sólo el código que esta relacionado con el error, hay demasiadas funciones innecesarias en tu pregunta, por lo que resulta confuso entender

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera ok lo editare

Comment: tienes dos mensajes en el titulo dice una cosa, pero despues mencionas uno diferente, pero en ambos aparece '' comillas, alli dice algo realmente y lo has quitado?

Comment: y que linea tira el error?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el de Member '' cannot be accessed with an instance reference ya no solucione, pero a  raiz de eso me salio el nuevo que dice en el titulo, pero no se a que se deba

Comment: En las partes donde menciono BizKitchenNEWConfiguration (y) NEWkitchen

Comment: `var NEWkitchen = new BizKitchenNEWConfiguration();` esto es una variable local? Porque veo que estas intentado acceder a ella en dos funciones fuera del contexto donde se crea

Comment: porque esto es estatico? public static string IsReleaseGroupedComms { get; set; } tu problema esta de seguro aca...

Comment: @gbianchi no amigo, quite el static del IsReleaseGroupedComms y el error persiste, usualmente por que sale ese error?

Comment: porque tratas de acceder a algo estatico desde una instancia de una clase, en lugar que desde la definicion de la clase